# R: add a character to a specific spot in string, trouble with regex syntax

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a list of string like so:
`batch1, batch2, batch3, batch10, batch11`

I am trying to add a 0 before the single digits `batch01, batch02, batch03, batch10, batch11`

I have found many similar questions and tried to write my own regex. I am very close, but I can't quite make it do what I want.

`Batch <- gsub('(.{5})([0-9]{1}\\b)','\\10\\2', Batch)`
outputs `batch01, batch02, batch 03, batch100, batch110`

`\\s` instead of `\\b` doesn't change any values

`sampleNames$Batch <- gsub('(.{5})([0-9]{1})','\\10\\2', sampleNames$Batch)` outputs `bacth01, batch02, batch03, batch010, batch011`

I've played around with a few other versions but I cannot seem to get it correct. I know this is a somewhat repetitive question, but I have not been able to alter previous solutions to do what I need to do.

Comment: The word "batch" does not change for all string you are working with?

Comment: batch is always the same, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can capture the last digit and the lower case letter before it as two groups, then in the replacement specify the backreference of the groups and the 0 in between.  Thus, it won't match the ones having two digits at the end of the string

```
sub("([a-z])(\\d)$", "\\10\\2", Batch)
[1] "batch01" "batch02" "batch03" "batch10" "batch11"
```

---

Or we may use `sprintf/str_pad` with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(Batch, "\\d+$", function(x) sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x)))
[1] "batch01" "batch02" "batch03" "batch10" "batch11"
```

#### data

```
Batch <- c("batch1", "batch2", "batch3", "batch10", "batch11")
```

Comment: that adds a 0 to the double digit numbers (010, 011)

Comment: @keenan can you test it as I couldn't find that case with the exxample provided

Answer (score 1):

Use

```r
sampleNames$Batch <- sub("(\\D|^)(\\d)$", "\\10\\2", sampleNames$Batch, perl=TRUE)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/EWQkO2/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \D                       non-digits (all but 0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution:

```
sapply(vec, function(x) {
  d <- gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d)", "\\2", x)
  if(nchar(d) == 1) {
    gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d)", "\\10\\2", x)
  } else {
    x
  }
})

   batch1    batch2    batch3   batch10   batch11 
"batch01" "batch02" "batch03" "batch10" "batch11"
```